# I'm having an issue escaping characters in this fragment of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jgrowl

I am trying to create a notifications system for my messaging project using [bootstrap-growl](https://github.com/mouse0270/bootstrap-growl). The system fetches new messages from mySQL perfectly and displays them with the notification. However, when the message has single quotes is when the game turns around.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $.growl( { 
        title: 'Samantha', 
        message: 'May we go to that pizza place tonight?'
    });
}, 3000);
```

That code works perfectly, yet it still goes wrong. 
Any advice on this issue will be greatly appreciated.
Remember, I'm still learning.

Comment: How exactly do you transmit values from MySQL to JavaScript?

Comment: No, let me explain: I echo a PHP variable into the script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass a PHP string to a JavaScript variable (and escape newlines)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines) - no need to see code, it's an all-time classic :)

Comment: That's the answer, thanks.